# div is not getting focus automatically when page loads

Tags: jquery, screen-readers

My requirement is when the page loads the div should automatically get focused, but When I click on div then only it is getting focused.

**HTML**

```
<span id="focusSuper" class="super-header align-center color-dark-red font-14 bold">Superannuation</span>
```

**Javascript**

`$("#focusSuper").attr("tabindex",-1).focus();`

**Css**

```
 span:focus{
background-color: black !important;
}
```

Comment: Please, post your completed code or provide a demo.

Comment: you can use css to do this:  input:focus {
    background-color: yellow;
}

Comment: It works. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kc6f9vkg/1/).

Comment: @alirezasafian when I click on that its getting focus.I want it get focus initially means on load of page

Comment: Why you don't add `tabindex` attribute to your html? Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kc6f9vkg/2/)